# How to indentify that given reponse is object, array or null. if all three is of type 'object'

Tags: javascript

If we get response data and I want to check that given response data is object, Array or null. These three are of same type then how to identify that given response is array or object or null.

Comment: For null, compare with null... `data === null`?

Comment: Arrays have a length property, objects don't. So you can check: <var>.hasOwnProperty(length). If true, it's an array, if false, it's an object.

Comment: [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose we have a var `foo` which can be anything of these three types. We could do it like this:

```
if (foo === null) {

} else if (Array.isArray(foo)) {

} else if (typeof foo === 'object') { // this may include dates and other types, classified as 'object'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply check the datatype by using `instanceof`.

In your case:

```
if (response instanceof Array || response instanceof Object || response === null) {
   //The variable 'response' is one of these types.
}
```

Check out the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).